# jQuery on or live?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

I recently deployed an infinite scroll to an app that I have build and found that sometimes I need to click twice for something to happen.

My app has likes, and once the dom had loaded, i need to click on the like button twice before it changes, then once i click on the other ones it's okay but I always have to click once for the app to almost "wake up"

Is there a better solution?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function runUpdate(url, item) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == '200') {
                    removeAddColor(item);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $('.mini-like').live('click', function(){
        $('.mini-like').toggle(
            function() {
                var item = $(this);
                var href = item.attr('href');
                runUpdate(href, item);
            },
            function() {
                var item = $(this);
                var rel = item.attr('rel');
                runUpdate(rel, item);
            }
        );
    });

    function removeAddColorFollow(item) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        if (item.hasClass('btn-success')) {
            $(item).removeClass('btn-success').attr('href', href).attr('rel', rel);
            $(item).find('i').removeClass('icon-white');
        } else {
            $(item).addClass('btn-success').attr('href', rel).attr('rel', href);
            $(item).find('i').addClass('icon-white');
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated in 1.7 in the favor of `on`, so please use `on` instead

Comment: @NiftyDude, You are correct. +1

Comment: what would a rewritten version for .live with .on look like then, I am not javascript expert...

Answer (score 1):

Well unless I'm completely wrong, you only attach the toggle event to .mini-like after it has been clicked once. Try to just replace

```
$('.mini-like').live('click', function() {...
```

With

```
$(function() {...
```

To attach the toggle event handler on document ready instead of on click

Answer (score 0):

The code `$('.mini-like').live('click',...` should be placed inside `$(document).ready()`

You can use `.on` in place of `.live`. As `.on` is a new method and `.live` is deprecated  now you should use `.on`

**UPDATE**
The re-written version will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.mini-like').on('click', function(){
    $('.mini-like').toggle(
        function() {
            var item = $(this);
            var href = item.attr('href');
            runUpdate(href, item);
        },
        function() {
            var item = $(this);
            var rel = item.attr('rel');
            runUpdate(rel, item);
        }
    );
 });

});

function runUpdate(url, item) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if (data == '200') {
                removeAddColor(item);
            }
        }
    });
}


function removeAddColorFollow(item) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    if (item.hasClass('btn-success')) {
        $(item).removeClass('btn-success').attr('href', href).attr('rel', rel);
        $(item).find('i').removeClass('icon-white');
    } else {
        $(item).addClass('btn-success').attr('href', rel).attr('rel', href);
        $(item).find('i').addClass('icon-white');
    };
}
```

Comment: You only need to put it inside `$(document).ready()` if the script isn't at the very bottom of the page. If you place your script right before the closing `</body>` tag, then you don't need it as the DOM will have been created at that point.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist great point, I think that's one of the common code that web devs repeatedly use because the online tutorials tell them so, not because they know why

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, The way of adding script after `</body>` should be avoided. It is not a standard practice.

Comment: @Imdad hm, he says `before the closing </body>`, not after

Comment: @NiftyDude, OK. but that does not makes it good anyway. Scripts should be placed in `<head>` as a good programming practice.

Comment: @Imdad any citation? I'm sure the accepted practice is to put reference to external scripts before `</body>` as browser can't fully parse DOM without finishing to download all `script`s

Comment: @Imdad and here's my citation, the yahoo dev http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: `The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.`

Comment: @NiftyDude, I was impressed with the content after reading it. But I was disappointed when I tested it practically. ref: http://s16.postimage.org/qg7rrnyol/j_Query_site.jpg

It shows loading statistics of jQuery website. Multiple script and css load parallaly.

Comment: @Imdad The thing to note here is that it won't, in anyway increase your app's performance automagically, as the browser still needs to download the resources no matter where you put them. The putting of scripts before `</body>` is to make sure that browser could parse the DOM before it starts to download anything, this in turn, would increase usability as users can start scrolling / looking around / sees things in your website, it is in short term, a perceived performance improvements.

Comment: @Imdad in any case, thanks for the remark about `scripts` location :) and the test :) (P.S, the screenshot is too small to see anything :p)

Comment: @Imdad what would a rewritten version look like then. All my code is place in the $(document).ready can you do a toggle with on?

Comment: @Imdad this rewritten actually causes the function to be fired off more than once and seems to duplicate every time you click it, ie 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 4, 4 becomes 8 etc...

Comment: @ApPeL, can you please shift the code to jsFiddle so that I can see

Comment: @Imdad jsfiddle.net/_entreprenerd/Rkd6W is this enough to take a look at?